# The diagram in ConTeXt remains invisible

Tags: diagrams, luatex, context

I found nice examples of Metapost, http://tex.loria.fr/prod-graph/zoonekynd/metapost/metapost.html.

When I use the example number 270, the pdf only contains a page number. 
Question: what I am doing wrong. I am a novice. I am using TeXworks, ConTeXt with LuaTeX.

I use the follow code:

```
\starttext
\startMPcode
beginfig(270)
    draw begingraph(3cm,2cm)
      gdraw "data1";
    endgraph;
endfig;
\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

I am unsure about the necessary data. I have tried to save data1.txt and data1.d with different content, such as

```
1 5
2 4
3 2
OR
0.0         0.0
0.2         0.447214
0.4         0.632456
OR
1cm 0cm
2cm 1cm
3cm 2cm
```

ConTeXt responds with the follow error message:

> ....
>   metapost        > initializing instance 'metafun' using format 'metafun'
>   metapost        > loading 'metafun' as 'C:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/metafun.mpiv' using method 'default'
>   metapost        > initializing number mode 'scaled'
>   metapost        > error:
>
> begingraph
>   ! Improper `addto'.
>    
>                      withpen
>   draw->...:also(EXPR0)else:doublepath(EXPR0)withpen
>                                                     .currentpen.fi.*op*
>    
>                      (
>   <*> beginfig(270) draw begingraph(
>                                     3cm,2cm) gdraw "data1"; endgraph; endfig; ;
>   ! Extra tokens will be flushed.
>    
>                      (
>   <*> beginfig(270) draw begingraph(
>                                     3cm,2cm) gdraw "data1"; endgraph; endfig; ;
>   endgraph
>   ! Isolated expression.
>    
>                      ;
>   <*> ...egingraph(3cm,2cm) gdraw "data1"; endgraph;
>                                                      endfig; ;
>
> [1]

Answer (score 4):

ConTeXt needs to redefine some of the definitions of graph module. To use these redefinitions, you have to use MP instance `graph`. To do so,

- Add `\usemodule[graph]` in your preamble.
- If you are using the `MPcode` environment, use `\startMPcode{graph}`.
- If you are using `MPpage` environment, use `\startMPpage[instance=graph]`.
- You do not need to add `begingraph(..) ... endgraph`

Here is a minimal example:

```
\usemodule[graph]
\starttext
\startMPpage[instance=graph]
draw begingraph(3in,2in);
    gdraw "data1.d";
endgraph;
\stopMPpage

\startMPcode{graph}
draw begingraph(3in,2in);
    gdraw "data1.d";
endgraph;
\stopMPcode

\stoptext
```

where `data1.d` was your first example.

BTW, if you are starting the plotting in ConTeXt, I would highly recommend that you start with `pgfplots`. It works in ConTeXt with a few quirks.

I am a big advocate of Metapost, how well it is integrated with ConTeXt, and how fast it runs. But, when it comes to plotting, pgfplot is a lot more polished than the metapost graph module.

Comment: Thank you very much @Aditya. Both diagrams are visible.  I will look into pgfplot

Comment: @Aditya Is there a better graph library for Metapost that's comparable to pgfplots, or is anyone working on it?

Comment: @JamesQi No. There is nothing as feature rich as pgfplots. But you can use pgfplots in context.